# How to find the maximum element of a list of turtles with a condition

Tags: netlogo

I would need to find the maximum of a list by a parameter (`price`).
The list contains three types of turtles, but only one of these elements is characterised by this parameter.
Specifically, I would like to find the house (`house`) with highest price and see its size (`dim`) and its owner (`landlord`). Price is house-own. 
I tried to define a local variable and to set it as the maximum of the turtle-set my-list as follows:

```
let selected_item max-one-of turtle-set my-list [prices]
```

but unfortunately it does not return a list of three elements (e.g. `(house 2, dim 4, landlord 3)`), but only one `(house 2)`. 
I think the problem is due to turtle-set rather than defining my-list, but maybe I am wrong.

UPDATE: 
What I would like to have is a list of three turtles `[[(house 2, dim 4, landlord 3)], [(house 3, dim 2, landlord 7), (house 4, dim 4, landlord 7)], ... ]` where the `house` is that one with highest `price`. 
Right now I have only one item, `(house 2)` and not the other information `(dim and landlord)`. 
So when I add the item on the top of the list of each turtle (`let-agent`), I have

`[[(house 2, dim 4, landlord 3)], **(house 3)** , [(house 5, dim 4, landlord 3)], ... ]`

The item in bold **(house 3)** comes from the code above, i.e. `let selected_item max-one-of` and I think this is because I am considering only the house and not the other turtles (`dim` and `landlord`). However, when I add the item to the lists of the turtles, I add them in the right way and this explains why I have a list partially correct (items not in bold in the example above). Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong in the selection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for the house with the maximum price and that's what it's giving you. So you can set the answer to a variable and then ask about its other characteristics. Something like:

```
let selected_item max-one-of turtle-set my-list [prices]
let size_selected [dim] of selected_item
let landlord_selected [landlord] of selected_item
```

Since the other types of turtles on the list don't have prices, this should work. But I think it would be clearer (and better coding in case you have price later) to only use the relevant turtles. In that case, you might want:

```
let list-houses turtle-set my-list with [breed = house]
let selected_item max-one-of list-houses [prices]
let size_selected [dim] of selected_item
let landlord_selected [landlord] of selected_item
let new-item (list selected-item size-selected landlord-selected)
let my-list fput new-item my-list
```

Comment: Thank you JenB. But the problem is that I have a list of turtles, one that uses the following format (house 2, dim 4, landlord 3)  and this selected item that shows only (house 2), and not the other two. I would like to have something that can be uniform. These items are added on the top of a list, so it would be better that they can have the same format. Something like: `[[(house 2, dim 4, landlord 3)], [(house 3, dim 2, landlord 7), (house 1, dim 4, landlord 7)], ... ]` and not `[[(house 2, dim 4, landlord 3), (house 3), ...]`, so I would need to pick from the list a selected item

Comment: with maximum price with also the other information in order to add this new set/list of parameters on the top of the list, once selected. What I would like to have is all the three variables/turtles corresponding to the turtle house with highest price. Otherwise I will need to add each of those items (`selected_item, size_selected`, and `landlord_selected`) to the list as one item `[[(house 2, dim 4, landlord 3)], ... ]`

Comment: try editing the question with example input and output to make it clear what you are trying to do

Comment: You didn't provide input and required output, but I have updated my answer so you can see how you create a list with the three bits of information and then add that list at the front of your existing list (which I have called my-list). Not sure where you are getting text like 'dim' from but this should get you on the right track.